# How to sort a link list based on a field of an object placed on the link list?

Tags: java, linked-list

How would I do the following I have a link list where I keep a Person object. This person object include String firstName, String lastName, String phoneNumber.

I want to sort the Object Person placed in my link list based on the last Name how can I do this?

Is there anything in the java library I can use?

Comment: Look into implementing a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and pass it into Collections.sort along with your List.

Comment: It's better to add your Person class definition rather than explaining the fields :)